# How to efficiently convert milliseconds offset to np.datetime64 in an ndarray of np.void

Tags: python, numpy

Okay, bear with me, I've only just started using NumPy.

I have a time series split over multiple files. Each file captures the data for a single day. The time field in each record is simply the of milliseconds since the start of that day

Now I am trying to read this data in using numpy, but I have trouble to convert the milliseconds to an `np.datetime64`.

What I have sofar:

```
t_base = np.datetime64(<some_date>) 

dtype = np.dtype([
    ("t", "i4"),
    ...<other fields here>...
])
data = np.fromfile(filename, dtype)
```

This gives me a one-dimensional `ndarray` of `np.void`. So far so good.

What I tried:

```
for record in np.nditer(data, op_flags["readwrite"]):
    record["t"] = t_base + np.timedelta64(int(record["t"]), "ms")
```

Unfortunately, this does not change the type. Instead it converts the constructed `datetime64` back to `int32`, which is incorrect because int32 does not have the range to capture time in milliseconds. So how do I get this done in an efficient manner? Obviously, after the conversion I have no need for the millisecond offset anymore.

Or alternatively, is there a way with `fromfile` to read an `int32` into a `int64` type? Then I can use an `int64` as timestamp instead of `datetime64`.

Comment: You can't change the dtype of a structured array field inplace.  You have to make a new array with a `datetime64` field, and copy data to it.

Comment: @hpaulj That makes sense. Is there a way to build a new `datetime64` column and reusing/referencing/... the other columns from the original `ndarray`? I have quite a lot of data